# Has Superman ever crushed a piece of coal into a diamond?

Tags: dc, superman

I listened to a recent episode of the podcast *Conan O'Brien Needs a Friend* where Conan off-handedly refers to Superman being able to crush a piece of coal into a diamond. Instead of simply enjoying the content of the podcast, I immediately combed the recesses of my memory to see if I could remember what he was referring to. It's entirely possible that Conan is simply misremembering this, but he said it with enough casual authority that it made me wonder if this was a popular comic book trope. Has Superman ever crushed a piece of coal into a diamond?

Comment: Zak Snyder thinks he can; https://youtu.be/ogpQdKbt8iw?t=10911 :-)

Comment: The trope is so well-known that is was parodied in _The Adventures of Baron Von Munchausen_: Sweaty, dirty Hephaestus does the trick for his beautiful wife Aphrodite (played by Uma Thurman).  “Oh,” she yawns.  “Another diamond.”

Comment: See the Superman audition skit on Saturday Night Live, starting at 4:50: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=niiNPH64Xv4.  The whole skit is really worth watching.

Comment: so Superman doesnt need Bruce's money

Comment: I saw the 1953 instance (in the late 1960's) and it's stuck with me ever since! While I still can't quite visualize the diamond crystal structure, it turns out that silicon uses the same one.

Comment: Not just Superman, but Supergirl too; https://i.stack.imgur.com/CpmwK.png

Comment: And Superman's son Jonathan in "*[Whatever Happened to the Man of Tomorrow?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superman:_Whatever_Happened_to_the_Man_of_Tomorrow%3F)*"; https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjgeC.png

Comment: Supergirl does it almost as often as Superman; https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGpSH.png

Comment: Rack up another one for Supergirl; https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJKJI.png

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Superman's done this trick on multiple occasions, notably in the movie *Superman III*

and Adventures of Superman Season 2 Episode 14 "Jungle Devil" (1953)

and Justice League Action episode "*Follow that Space Cab*"

and Supergirl Season 4, Episode 9

and Smallville Season 5, Episode 12

But also so often in the golden and silver age comics that it's essentially impossible to identify which occasion your question is referring to.

[image]

[image: https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Superman_Vol_1_280]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[![enter image description here][9]][9]

[image]

[image: The Kingdom - Vol 1 #2]

Comment: Also *Superman: True Brit*, where "his attempt to solve Britain's budget crisis by converting coal to diamonds also backfires, as it creates a coal shortage and drastically lowers the value of the diamonds."

Comment: not only does he create diamonds, they are cut and ground as well!

Comment: Clearly, the recesses of my mind are completely empty considering how many examples there are.

Comment: @ths And just by luck, I think I should have a golden ring with a missing stone in my pocket.. Ha, there it is!

Comment: @JBH - I'm terrified that someone is going to notice that I've not identified which comics these panels come from.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots And does the DeBeers cartel get on his case about it?  Diamonds aren't nearly as rare as they'd have us believe...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman It's a highly satirical piece, which doesn't try to emulate realism in any way. One of Superman's primary villains is a fellow who calls himself Batman because Superman, in a civilian guys, accidentally buried a cricket bat in his torso. A lot of the humor is based on the idea of that all of his attempts to help just get scorn from the general populace, because he doesn't fit the norm.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Especially with this caped doofus going around making more diamonds willy nilly.